# 「だが」は単なる「が」に言い換えることができますか

Tags: particle-が, copula

この[リンク](https://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/30517/)にある「ちょっと〇〇するだけのつもりが、つい〇〇してしまった」の「つもりが」は実際は「つもりだが」の意味になっていると思えるんですけど、これは例外なのですか。それともどんな名詞の後ろにでも「だが」ではなく単に「が」が来られるということですか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「つもりが」の「が」は「私が」の「が」と同じ名詞につく格助詞であり、「きれいだが」のように動詞・形容詞につく接続助詞ではありません。なので「つもりが」は「つもりだが」とは違う意味を表します。

違うとは言っても、用法的には似たような意味になります（そもそもこの二つの「が」は語源的に関係しているので）。この意味の「～が」は、事前に想定していた内容を表す名詞句 (noun phrase) をとり、「X と思っていたのに（結果は／実際は） Y」と同様の意味を表します。そのため、形式名詞「つもり」「はず」を含め、予期、期待を表す言葉と一緒に使われやすい言い方です。

> 今日は休む予定が、急な仕事が入ってしまった。
>   大切にしまっておいたはずが、いつのまにかなくなっていた。
>   できないと思っていたのが、案外あっさり解決した。

英語に訳すと単なる "but" ではなく、"but ended up" とか "but in reality" まで含んだ意味合いです。

**追記:** 英語でも、例えば

> I've had a lot of worries in my life, most of **which** never happened. (pronoun)
>   A really tip-top man, **with** all his wrongheadedness. (preposition)

のように、（しばしば構造は逆ですが）接続詞でないものを逆接の意味がこもった説明のために使うことがあると思います。このように、文法上の役割とは別に、機能として特定の気持ちを伝える言い回しと似たようなものだと考えるといいかもしれません。

---

リンク先の回答では「〜だけするつもりだった**の**が」と言い換えている人がいますが、これは「つもりだった」にさらにこの「が」をつけようとした時の表現です。あくまで「が」の前は名詞になります。

Comment: ということは、この「が」は格助詞として働いているといっても、文にある動詞の主語をマークしているわけではないということですか。

Comment: @lightweaver 辞書を調べても見つからないのですが、格助詞だとは思います（ただしもはや「主格」とは言えないかもしれないですが）。意味的には副詞節に近いので副助詞と言えなくもないですが、「が」自体の意味によって副詞的になっているというより、前に来る名詞の意味によってこのようなニュアンスが生じているというほうが正しいと思います。

Answer (score 6):

探してもこの用法に関する解説がなかなか見つかりませんので私も今一つ確信が持てませんが、
この「が」は、逆説の接続助詞の「が」ではなく、主語を表す格助詞の「が」の用法の一つだと思っています。
そのため、名詞（体言）の後ろに来るのは当たり前といえます。

似たような表現に、

「鍵を閉めたはずが、実は開いていた」
「前は小さかったのが、いつの間にか大きくなっている」
「遊びのつもりが、つい本気になってしまった」

などがあります。

要するに、「XがYになった」「Xが実はYだった」などの表現の延長みたいなものかと思います。
この場合Xに当たるのは「ちょっと〇〇するだけのつもり」で、
Yに当たるのは「つい〇〇してしまうこと」になりますが、
最後の「～ことになった」を省略したことで今の形になったのではないでしょうか。

確かに逆説の接続詞・接続助詞のほうの「が」と意味は似ていますが、
ニュアンスが微妙に違うように思います。
もしかしたら接続詞・接続助詞の「が」はもともと、このような用法から生まれたのでしょうか？
ちょっと気になります。