# Is it true that のが sometimes means のですが?

Tags: grammar, particle-が

のが would usually mark a subject, but someone once told me it could mean のですが. Is this true or did I get bad information?

This is from ビジテリアン大祭

> 私がニュウファウンドランドの、トリニテイの港に着きましたのは、恰度大祭の前々日でありました。事によると、間に合わないと思ったのが、うまい工合に参りましたので、大へんよろこびました。

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64945/7810

Comment: Thank you, that helps. In the passage I quoted, isn't the narrator still the subject of 参る?

Comment: Ah, no. Try looking up うまくいく (sorry I can't stay up anymore).

Comment: The linked question seems enough to me. Would you mind closing this as a duplicate?